# 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__' with class variables

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to create a python class to control stepper motors using my Raspberry Pi. It mostly works, however I keep on getting an "'instancemethod' object has no attribute `'__getitem__'` error whenever I define a list as a class variable. The error message lists this piece of code as the culprit but I can't see anything wrong with it if seq[self.StepCounter][pin]!=0:.  It will work if I define it as an instance variable or a global variable though.
This is my code:
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import time
    debug = True

```
class stepper:
    clockwise = []
    clockwise = range(0,4)
    clockwise[0] = [1,0,0,0]
    clockwise[1] = [0,1,0,0]
    clockwise[2] = [0,0,1,0]
    clockwise[3] = [0,0,0,1]
    def __init__(self,pin1,pin2,pin3,pin4):
        GPIO.setwarnings(False)
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        self.pin1 = pin1
        self.pin2 = pin2
        self.pin3 = pin3
        self.pin4 = pin4
        self.StepCounter = 0
        self.pinarray = [pin1,pin2,pin3,pin4]
        for pin in self.pinarray:
            if debug == True:
                print "Setup pin " + str(pin)
            GPIO.setup(pin,GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.output(pin, False)
        self.stepNum = 512.0
        self.coilNum = 4.0

    def setup(self,stepNum,coilNum):
        self.stepNum = float(stepNum)
        self.coilNum = float(coilNum)
        self.partNum = self.coilNum * self.stepNum

    def clockwise(self,speed):
        seq = stepper.clockwise
        self.WaitTime = (1.0 / (self.stepNum * self.coilNum)) * speed
        for pin in range(0, 4):
            xpin = self.pinarray[pin]
            if seq[self.StepCounter][pin]!=0:
              GPIO.output(xpin, True)
            else:
              GPIO.output(xpin, False)
        self.StepCounter += 1
        if (self.StepCounter==len(seq)):
            self.StepCounter = 0
        if (self.StepCounter<0):
            self.StepCounter = len(seq)
        time.sleep(self.WaitTime)

print "Adding Motor Instance"    
motor = stepper(24,25,8,7)
print "Spinning Motor"
while "True":
    motor.clockwise(5)
```

Please could someone tell me what's wrong with it and explain why. Thanks

Comment: Not that this will fix it, but why initiate clockwise so strange? Just do it in one statement :-P

Comment: can you give the exact full error?

Comment: and please initialize clockwise as : `clockwise = [[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]]` instead of your mess! ;-)

Comment: You have two attributes called `clockwise`, a list and a method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You didn't post the full traceback, but I can take a guess:

```
def clockwise(self,speed):
    seq = stepper.clockwise
    self.WaitTime = (1.0 / (self.stepNum * self.coilNum)) * speed
    for pin in range(0, 4):
        xpin = self.pinarray[pin]
        if seq[self.StepCounter][pin]!=0:
```

You set `seq` equal to the method `stepper.clockwise` on the first line.  Then a few lines later you try to index into it: `seq[self.StepCounter]`.  But what does it mean to get the `self.StepCounter`-th element of a method?

Nothing, because:

```
'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

You shouldn't use `clockwise` both as the name of a list and as the name of a method; only the last-executed definition will hold, so by the time you get to `seq = stepper.clockwise`, it's the method, not the list.

Comment: Also, `clockwise = range(0,4)` makes `clockwise=[]` unnecessary; you don't need to "declare" clockwise before assigning a list to it. A single `clockwise = [ [1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,1] ]` will suffice.